# Issue while creating Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using the below command to create ingress but getting the error

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Getting the below Error after executing the command:

```
namespace/ingress-nginx unchanged
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx unchanged
configmap/ingress-nginx-controller unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission unchanged
service/ingress-nginx-controller configured
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller configured
ingressclass.networking.k8s.io/nginx unchanged
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission configured
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"batch/v1\",\"kind\":\"Job\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"helm.sh/hook\":\"pre-install,pre-upgrade\",\"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy\":\"before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded\"},\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"Helm\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/version\":\"1.1.0\",\"helm.sh/chart\":\"ingress-nginx-4.0.10\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-create\",\"namespace\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"Helm\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/version\":\"1.1.0\",\"helm.sh/chart\":\"ingress-nginx-4.0.10\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-create\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"args\":[\"create\",\"--host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc\",\"--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)\",\"--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission\"],\"env\":[{\"name\":\"POD_NAMESPACE\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"}}}],\"image\":\"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"IfNotPresent\",\"name\":\"create\",\"securityContext\":{\"allowPrivilegeEscalation\":false}}],\"nodeSelector\":{\"kubernetes.io/os\":\"linux\"},\"restartPolicy\":\"OnFailure\",\"securityContext\":{\"runAsNonRoot\":true,\"runAsUser\":2000},\"serviceAccountName\":\"ingress-nginx-admission\"}}}}\n"},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.1.0","helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-4.0.10"}},"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.1.0","helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-4.0.10"}},"spec":{"$setElementOrder/containers":[{"name":"create"}],"containers":[{"image":"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660","name":"create","securityContext":{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":false}}]}}}}
to:
Resource: "batch/v1, Resource=jobs", GroupVersionKind: "batch/v1, Kind=Job"
Name: "ingress-nginx-admission-create", Namespace: "ingress-nginx"
for: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml": Job.batch "ingress-nginx-admission-create" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-create", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"admission-webhook", "app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.1.0", "controller-uid":"1addd774-2f1c-4641-8f3b-83ccf7986eb2", "helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-4.0.10", "job-name":"ingress-nginx-admission-create"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"create", Image:"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660", Command:[]string(nil), Args:[]string{"create", "--host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc", "--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)", "--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission"}, WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort(nil), EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar{core.EnvVar{Name:"POD_NAMESPACE", Value:"", ValueFrom:(*core.EnvVarSource)(0xc00a475d00)}}, Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"IfNotPresent", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(0xc007794b40), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]core.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:"OnFailure", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc00a171990), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string{"kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}, ServiceAccountName:"ingress-nginx-admission", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc01415f080), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", SetHostnameAsFQDN:(*bool)(nil), Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), PreemptionPolicy:(*core.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), Overhead:core.ResourceList(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]core.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil)}}: field is immutable
Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"batch/v1\",\"kind\":\"Job\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"helm.sh/hook\":\"post-install,post-upgrade\",\"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy\":\"before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded\"},\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"Helm\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/version\":\"1.1.0\",\"helm.sh/chart\":\"ingress-nginx-4.0.10\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-patch\",\"namespace\":\"ingress-nginx\"},\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/component\":\"admission-webhook\",\"app.kubernetes.io/instance\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"Helm\",\"app.kubernetes.io/name\":\"ingress-nginx\",\"app.kubernetes.io/version\":\"1.1.0\",\"helm.sh/chart\":\"ingress-nginx-4.0.10\"},\"name\":\"ingress-nginx-admission-patch\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"args\":[\"patch\",\"--webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission\",\"--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)\",\"--patch-mutating=false\",\"--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission\",\"--patch-failure-policy=Fail\"],\"env\":[{\"name\":\"POD_NAMESPACE\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"}}}],\"image\":\"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"IfNotPresent\",\"name\":\"patch\",\"securityContext\":{\"allowPrivilegeEscalation\":false}}],\"nodeSelector\":{\"kubernetes.io/os\":\"linux\"},\"restartPolicy\":\"OnFailure\",\"securityContext\":{\"runAsNonRoot\":true,\"runAsUser\":2000},\"serviceAccountName\":\"ingress-nginx-admission\"}}}}\n"},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.1.0","helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-4.0.10"}},"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.1.0","helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-4.0.10"}},"spec":{"$setElementOrder/containers":[{"name":"patch"}],"containers":[{"image":"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660","name":"patch","securityContext":{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":false}}]}}}}
to:
Resource: "batch/v1, Resource=jobs", GroupVersionKind: "batch/v1, Kind=Job"
Name: "ingress-nginx-admission-patch", Namespace: "ingress-nginx"
for: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml": Job.batch "ingress-nginx-admission-patch" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"ingress-nginx-admission-patch", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"admission-webhook", "app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx", "app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.1.0", "controller-uid":"8276c22c-d78f-4212-9104-cd670e31d6e6", "helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-4.0.10", "job-name":"ingress-nginx-admission-patch"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"patch", Image:"k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660", Command:[]string(nil), Args:[]string{"patch", "--webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission", "--namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)", "--patch-mutating=false", "--secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission", "--patch-failure-policy=Fail"}, WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort(nil), EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar{core.EnvVar{Name:"POD_NAMESPACE", Value:"", ValueFrom:(*core.EnvVarSource)(0xc00a992ce0)}}, Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"IfNotPresent", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(0xc01425a840), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]core.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:"OnFailure", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc00676e9d0), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string{"kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}, ServiceAccountName:"ingress-nginx-admission", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc00dc0fd00), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", SetHostnameAsFQDN:(*bool)(nil), Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), PreemptionPolicy:(*core.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), Overhead:core.ResourceList(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]core.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil)}}: field is immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

i used to have the same problem, it seems broken version.
resolved it using :

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on error you're having, you had already installed `ingress nginx` before and it was installed using `helm`.

Correct way to upgrade release is to use [`helm upgrade`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) command.

---

Below the example:

1. Checking which `ingress nginx` is installed

   ```
   $ helm list -n ingress-nginx

   NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
   ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx   20              2021-12-07 09:49:21.455650667 +0000 UTC deployed        ingress-nginx-4.0.13    1.1.0
   ```
2. Update `helm` repository to catch the latest available versions

   ```
   $ helm repo update

   Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
   ...Successfully got an update from the "ingress-nginx" chart repository
   ```
3. Upgrade your `ingress nginx`:

   ```
   $ helm upgrade --reuse-values ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx

   Release "ingress-nginx" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
   NAME: ingress-nginx
   LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Dec 28 08:09:53 2021
   NAMESPACE: ingress-nginx
   STATUS: deployed
   ```

---

**Note!** You might need to delete and then install `ingress-nginx` from scratch if some components were changed/broken when manifest was applied on top of the helm installation. If you have any changes in `values.yaml`, consider saving the file somewhere and then adding it.

To do so you need to perform these steps:

1. Uninstall chart

   ```
   $ helm uninstall ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx

   release "ingress-nginx" uninstalled
   ```
2. Delete namespace where `ingress nginx` was installed to clean anything's left:

   ```
   $ kubectl delete ns ingress-nginx

   namespace "ingress-nginx" deleted
   ```
3. And install it from scratch:

   ```
   $ helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace

   NAME: ingress-nginx
   LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Dec 28 08:20:48 2021
   NAMESPACE: ingress-nginx
   STATUS: deployed
   REVISION: 1
   ```

---

Useful links:

- [Upgrade ingress-nginx using helm](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/upgrade/#with-helm)